# regular expression help in R

Tags: regex, r

I have data that looks like this, where the negative sign is a suffix
at the end of the numeric.

```
"general_amount"
"0000000441244"
"0000000127769-"
"0000000043819"
"0000000522600-"
```

Can someone help me find a regular expression to produce the desired output below.

```
"general_amount"
 441244
-127769
 43819
-522600
```

Comment: completely lost, and had enough wrestled with it

Comment: Is the "general_amount" text part of the data or just your heading? Why use a regexp? If your data is either a positive number or a number with a - suffix there's other ways of detecting the negatives.

Answer (score 9):

```
sub('^0*([^-]*)(-?)$', '\\2\\1', x)

## [1] "general_amount" "441244"         "-127769"        "43819"          "-522600"
```

`^0*` matches all leading `0` characters.
`[^-]*` matches all non-`-` characters.
`-?` matches zero or one `-` character.
Finally, the `$` matches the end of the string.

The middle two pieces are captured with `()`, as `\\1` and `\\2`, and printed in reverse order.

Comment: i'm curious.. could you also explain what's going on here?  :)

Comment: It's simple, but I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: thanks Matthew that will be great if you could add what is going here.

Comment: thanks Matthew for the answers both the questions and the explanations

Answer (score 1):

Using *gsub* , with another idea.

The idea is to divide the input into 3 elements

1. series of 0       :(^0+)
2. series of number   :([0-9]+)
3. find the '-' 1 or zero times     : (-?)"

   ```
      as.numeric(gsub("(^0+)([0-9]+)(-?)","\\3\\2",tt))
      [1]  441244 -127769   43819 -522600
   ```

Comment: This specifies that there must be a leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

Dude it took me 3 hours  to find answer to your question

```
sed -re 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]0+([0-9]+)(-?)/\2\1/g' anyfile.txt
```

But in the end i did it. May have some short coming but i got it nearly

Comment: That's OK for a `sed` solution, but a solution in `R` was requested.  It matters; in `R`, the `"` characters are printed to the console around string values, and are not part of the values themselves.  Thus you don't want the `(")` at the end (and why capture?).  And the `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` at the beginning can be simply a `^`.

Comment: thanks buddy , i am also learning . so thanks. Actually i did that because i wanted to allow double quotes  `"` before 0

Comment: I'm sure that you found this question due to the `regex` tag, but perhaps now is the time to install `R` and play with that.  It is quite the playground, if you like data.